# Can't get attribute 'text_process' on <module '__main__' from 'X:\\Software\\anaconda\\Scripts\\flask-script.py'

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have created a flask application, which refers to a pickle file for prediction. inside the pickle file, the pipeline is referred as follows:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
('bow', CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_process)),  # strings to token integer counts
('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),  # integer counts to weighted TF-IDF scores
('classifier', MultinomialNB()),  # train on TF-IDF vectors w/ Naive Bayes classifier])
pickle.dump(pipeline, open('model.pkl', 'wb'))
model= pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
```

Then I have defined the flask as below:

```
import numpy as np
def text_process(mess):
 nopunc = [char for char in mess if char not in string.punctuation]
 nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)    
 return [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')]
 import pickle
 from nltk.corpus import stopwords
 import string
 from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
 app = Flask(__name__)
 model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
 @app.route('/')
 def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
 @app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
 def predict():
  '''
   For rendering results on HTML GUI
  '''
   int_features = [ request.form.values()]

   prediction = model.predict(int_features)

  return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='Classification is {}'.format(prediction))
 @app.route('/predict_api',methods=['POST'])
  def predict_api():
   '''
   For direct API calls throught request
  '''
   data = request.get_json(force=True)
   prediction = model.predict([np.array(list(data.values()))])

output = prediction[0]
return jsonify(output)
if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(debug=True)
```

But when I execute the flask using flask run command or when I deploy it using azure app service, the 'text_process' function is not taken into memory and I am getting the below error

```
"Can't get attribute 'text_process' on <module '__main__' from 'X:\\Software\\anaconda\\Scripts\\flask-script.py'>"
```

But at the same time, if I execute the app.py using the command "python app.py", It works fine.
Could you please help on this

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom unpickler will resolve the issue

```
class MyCustomUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
def find_class(self, module, name):
    if module == "__main__":
        module = "app"
    return super().find_class(module, name)

with open('model/model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    unpickler = MyCustomUnpickler(f)
    model = unpickler.load()
```